# Error messages when trying to run byobu in solaris

Tags: installation, solaris, tmux, byobu

I was able to successfully perform

```
'./configure --prefix=/my/path;make;make install'
```

on the byobu source code.
I have also installed tmux-1.8.
But when I try running

```
byobu
```

or

```
byobu-tmux
```

I get lot of errors saying find is not able to access files(it can't since i want to build byobu on a system locally without full access) 
The error message about which I want to ask is

```
install: null was not found anywhere!
```

This is the last message after a bunch of errors which are of the form 
find:[cannot read|stat() error |cycle detected] filename

(tmux 1.8 and byobu work perfectly well on my other desktop(for which i have full access)).

Do I need to build byobu again?Or make changes in the byobu scripts?

Comment: Not sure if you're aware of this, but you're not suppose to cross post the same question on the various StackExchange websites. I saw this same question on unix & linux, http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73129/error-messages-when-trying-to-install-byobu-in-solaris

Comment: I didn't know..I have removed it from unix and linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

byobu-tmux runs byobu-janitor --force

inside that a command 'install' is used that is not present in solaris ,it is same as touch filename ;chmod xxx filename

just replaced it and the error message goes away.still not able to run it though..new errors